# How do I stack components on top of each other in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, components, react-redux

I'm trying to stack some components on top of some base map layer that I have, but I'm finding that the other components seem to always go below my map.

I've created a *functional statemeless component* for my map.

#### map.js

```
const divStyle = {
  position: 'absolute',
  zIndex: -1
};

return (
  <ReactMapGL
    style={divStyle}
    width={props.width}
    height={props.height}
    latitude={props.latitude}
    longitude={props.longitude}
    mapStyle={mapStyle}
    zoom={props.zoom}
    preventStyleDiffing={true}
    onViewportChange={(viewport) => {
      updateViewport(viewport);
    }}/>);
```

And then I have the following section in my component to stack:

```
const divStyle = {
  position: 'absolute',
  zIndex: 0,
  top: '0px',
  left: '0px',
};

<div>
  {Map({
    latitude: this.props.map.latitude,
    longitude: this.props.map.longitude,
    width: this.props.map.width,
    height: this.props.map.height,
    zoom: this.props.map.zoom,
    updateViewport: this.props.updateMapViewport
  })}
  <Panel style={divStyle}></Panel>
  <div style={divStyle}>Hello world!</div>
</div>
```

I thought that maybe the fact that I'm calling `Map()` instead of using `<Map/>` had something to do with it, but that doesn't sound right. When I checked the Dev Console, I saw that my `map div` had `positive:relative`, while the other `divs` didn't have any `position`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, `<Panel>` doesn't actually take a style prop. Because of that, it can't accept the `position: absolute` style.